# Using generic or nor knowing type of a property in a method

Tags: c#, generics, web-config

I want to write a method that takes two parameters:

1. string [PropertyName],
2. unknown [new propertyValue]  --- could be a string, int, or bool

I am using it to update key values in the `web.config` app settings keys. So, if I want to update a string value in the settings, e.g. `GlobalEmail`, I could use the method as so:

```
UpdateSettingsKeyToNewValue("GlobalEmail", "newAddress@outlook.com");
```

Or I could update a switch like so:

```
UpdateSettingsKeyToNewValue("IsUserSet", false);
```

How could I go about doing this? The current code is a basic as follows, but not sure how to type check, and then cast correctly, and then apply the new value.

```
public void UpdateKeyValue(string propertyName, Object newValue)
{
    Type genericType = typeof(newValue["newValue"]);  //not sure how to get here....
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);           
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(propertyName);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(propertyName, newValue);
    config.Save();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do,

```
public void UpdateKeyValue<T>(string propertyName, T newValue)
{
    Configuration config = 
        WebConfigurationManager
            .OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(propertyName);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(propertyName, newValue.ToString());
    config.Save();
}
```

You are writing to the configuration file after all, so `ToString` should do the trick. And no need to worry about *types* or *generics* per say.

As mentioned by @Tomek this will work the same way as using simply `object`

```
public void UpdateKeyValue(string propertyName, object newValue)
{ ... }
```

However, I'm inclined to say that using a type parameter will give better type safety, and improved performance (no value type boxing).

Comment: But in this case isn't the `T` parameter useless? Couldn't we just pass an `object` paremeter?

Comment: I poorly created the example. Yes you are correct now that I think about it. We pull things from the config file, into a seperate class, and set them by casting to correctly type from string. So I was overlooking the first step "Will always be string" and going to find the property in the preparation class we use to handle these config properties. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomek They behave the same; however, I wonder if there is a performance gain by using a type parameter, since there is no boxing of value types, and no virtual method invocations in the case of `ToString`

Comment: I should of not used the Web.Config as an example, as we use a getter to get these settings, and cast them to the type we need, [bool, int] whatever. So will not always be a string. I am basically needing a way to take to params for a class, a property name as string, and the new value of that property. SO I can then use a reflection or something to loop through all properties in the target class, find the right one, and update the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Type genericType = newValue.GetType();
```

This should do it, but I don't see you're using it anywhere!

Comment: I also cam eacross this just now.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433856/passing-anonymous-type-as-method-parameters

Comment: So is this what you're looking for?